# How do I do to make a sound file play to two different devices?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, audio, multiprocessing, python-sounddevice

I'm trying to play a sound file play to two different devices and so I've tried the multiprocessing and threading modules but it doesn't yield the wanted result

At first, I wanted to execute the function that plays the file twice at the same time but then I realized that it wasn't possible so I want to execute both in a very small time window. I tried the threading and multiprocessing module to make two processes. after I tried to simply execute it with the play function returning immediately so it can execute the next play but it just plays them one after the other

```
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
from multiprocessing import Process
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
parser.add_argument("filename", help="audio file to be played back")
args = parser.parse_args()

def _play_(d):
    try:
       data, fs = sf.read(args.filename, dtype='float32')
       sd.play(data, fs, device=d, blocking = False)
       status = sd.wait()
    if status:
        parser.exit('Error during playback: ' + str(status))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        parser.exit('\nInterrupted by user')
    except Exception as e:
        parser.exit(type(e).__name__ + ': ' + str(e))


if __name__ == '__main__':
        Process(target =_play_(8),name = 'playing1').start()
        Process(target =_play_(9),name = 'playing2').start()
```

I expect it to play twice the file I specified to two different devices at almost the same time but instead, it just plays one at a time

Comment: You are using `Process` wrong. The argument `target` is supposed to be a callable object, but in your case it isn't! Also, try not using `Process` at all. You should try using two instances of `sd.OutputStream`, each with its callback function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'm working on the solution I think what i need to do is somehow make sounddevice believe that the devices are one and the same and have their own callback functions as you said